# Segmentation Fault when using MPI_Isend

Tags: c, mpi

The aim of my program is calculate the electrostatic potential between an inner conductor and an outer conductor by splitting it up into a grid and then into grid slices. Each processor gets a slice and runs the calculations on each slice. I send data between processors using MPI_Isend and MPI_Irecv. When testing the code I get a segmentation fault:

```
[physnode5:81440] *** Process received signal ***
[physnode5:81440] Signal: Segmentation fault (11)
[physnode5:81440] Signal code: Address not mapped (1)
[physnode5:81440] Failing at address: 0x58
[physnode5:81440] [ 0] /lib64/libpthread.so.0(+0xf5d0)[0x2ab8069df5d0]
[physnode5:81440] [ 1] /opt/yarcc/libraries/openmpi/2.1.0/1/default/lib/libmpi.so.20(ompi_request_default_wait+0xd)[0x2ab8066495ed]
[physnode5:81440] [ 2] /opt/yarcc/libraries/openmpi/2.1.0/1/default/lib/libmpi.so.20(MPI_Wait+0x5d)[0x2ab80667a00d]
[physnode5:81440] [ 3] ./mpi_tezt.exe[0x400ffc]
[physnode5:81440] [ 4] /lib64/libc.so.6(__libc_start_main+0xf5)[0x2ab806c0e3d5]
[physnode5:81440] [ 5] ./mpi_tezt.exe[0x4009b9]
[physnode5:81440] *** End of error message ***
```

when this bit of code is executed. please not i have ssh'ed into a cluster. The file name is mpi_tezt.exe (yes i mispelled it).
I have checked the arrays I want to send are correctly allocated and the send and recv are not sending or receiving data that isn't there (i.e sending data outside range of array.
My code for the MPI_Isend and MPI_Irecv is as follows:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <mpi.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  /*MPI Specific Variables*/
  int my_size, my_rank, up, down;
  MPI_Request reqU, reqD, sreqU, sreqD;
  MPI_Status rUstatus, rDstatus, sUstatus, sDstatus;

   /*Physical Dimensions*/
  double Linner = 5.0;/*mm*/
  double Rinner = 1.0;/*mm*/
  double phi_0 = 1000.0;/*V*/

  /*Other Variables*/
  int grid_size = 100;
  int slice;
  int x,y;
  double grid_res_y = 0.2;
  double grid_res_x = 0.1;
  int xboundary, yboundary;

  MPI_Init(&argc, &argv);
  MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &my_rank);
  MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &my_size);

  /*Determining neighbours*/
  if (my_rank != 0) /*if statemets used to stop highest and lowest rank neighbours arent outside 0 - my_size-1 range of ranks*/
    {
      up = my_rank-1;
    }
  else
    {
      up = 0;
    }

  if(my_rank != my_size-1)
    {
      down = my_rank+1;
    }
  else
    {
      down = my_size-1;
    }

  /*cross-check: presumed my_size is a factor of gridsize else there are odd sized slices and this is not coded for*/
  if (grid_size%my_size != 0)
    {
      printf("ERROR - number of procs =  %d, this is not a factor of grid_size %d\n", my_size, grid_size);
      exit(0);
    }

  /*Set Up Distributed Data Approach*/
  slice = grid_size/my_size;

  yboundary = Linner/grid_res_y; /*y grid index of inner conductor wall*/ 
  xboundary = Rinner/grid_res_x; /*x grid and individual array index of inner conductor wall*/


  double phi[slice+2][grid_size]; /*extra 2 rows to allow for halo data*/

  for (y=0; y < slice+2; y++)
    {
      for (x=0; x < grid_size; x++)
        { 
          phi[y][x] = 0.0;
        }
    }

  if(my_rank == 0) /*Boundary Containing rank does 2 loops. One over part with inner conductor and one over part without inner conductor*/
    {
      for(y=0; y < slice+1; y++)
        {
          for(x=xboundary; x < grid_size; x++)
            {
              phi[y][x] = phi_0;
            }
        }   
    }


  if (my_rank < my_size-1)
    {
      /*send top most strip up one node to be recieved as bottom halo*/
      MPI_Isend(&phi[1][0], grid_size  , MPI_DOUBLE, down, 1, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &sreqU);  
      /*recv top halo from up one node*/
      MPI_Irecv(&phi[slice+1][0], grid_size, MPI_DOUBLE, down, 2, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &reqU);
    }

  if (my_rank > 0)
    {
      /*recv top halo from down one node*/
      MPI_Irecv(&phi[0][0], grid_size , MPI_DOUBLE, up, 2, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &reqD);
      /*send bottom most strip down one node to be recieved as top halo*/
      MPI_Isend(&phi[slice][0], grid_size , MPI_DOUBLE, up, 1, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &sreqD);
    }

  if (my_rank<my_size-1)
    {
      /*Wait for send to down one rank to complete*/
      MPI_Wait(&sreqD, &sDstatus);
      /*Wait for recieve from up one rank to complete*/
      MPI_Wait(&reqD, &rDstatus);
    }

  if (my_rank>0)
    {
      /*Wait for send to up down one rank to complete*/
      MPI_Wait(&sreqU, &sUstatus);
      /*Wait for recieve from down one rank to complete*/
      MPI_Wait(&reqU, &rUstatus);
    }


  MPI_Finalize();

  return 0;
}
```

I have been testing on 2 processors (ranks 0 and 1) with the hope of extending it to more.

Any ideas where the fault may lie?

Comment: Way, waaaay too much code.

Comment: Have you tried running under a debugger? It'll generally take you to the point where the segmentation fault occurred, with a complete snapshot of the program state at that time. If you can't do that for some reason, you can set `ulimit -c` to allow a core dump, and debug the core file instead.

Comment: there are too many places for this to go wrong. However have you changed that slice and grid_size are reasonable. even after that check there plenty of array refs that can go astray.

And these lines:
  if (my_rank = A_proc)

will not do what you want them to

Comment: I would suggest using Valgrind to help determine the violation that is causing your segmentation fault

Comment: Note the word _minimal_ in [mcve].  Try to center the code you post around the specific problem you are asking about, even if you have to carve it up some to illustrate.

Comment: _At line 206 I send data between processors using_ `MPI_Isend` _and_ `MPI_Irecv`. _When testing the code i get a segmentation fault_.  Line 206 is hard to find.  Please mark location of seg fault in your posted code. (preferably in ALL CAPS so it is easy to find. :)

Comment: edited to only include relevant bit of code and gives explanation of the variables used

Comment: Now this is Minimal but no more Complete

Comment: The most obvious candidate for a crash is `MPI_Irecv(phi[slice+1][0] (...)` depending on the value of slice.

Comment: Now that you've updated the code, I'd check how the calculation `slice = grid_size/my_size;` turns out.

Comment: @brothir In the case of 2 processors, the value of slice was 50 as expected

Comment: @Aaron Do you know which process crashes? Put some printf before, after and in between the sends and recvs to see how far you get before it crashes.

Comment: @brothir I added a print statement after all the sends and receives. They were all printed but the error message still appears

Comment: @brothir i added print statements before the each wait statements. The one place between the wait  for sreqD was not printed. Maybe a problem with MPI_Wait?

Comment: `grid_res_x` and `grid_res_y` are _unitialized_ and have random values. Particularly, this can cause `xboundary` to be [maximally] negative. This causes a segfault in `for (x = xboundary; x < grid_size; x++) phi[y][x] = phi_0;`

Comment: @CraigEstey I have tried initialising those variables. No change

Comment: Initializing those values may not be the _only_ fix you need, but it _is_ the first one. I'm running your code here. So, what initialization values are you using?

Comment: @CraigEstey I have used grid_res_x = 0.1 and grid_res_y = 0. 2.

Comment: When I add that, I get `xboundary` is 10 and `yboundary` is 25. The program exits normally (i.e. _no_ segfault). There are no `printf` for results so it's hard to say beyond that point.

Comment: @CraigEstey I will add the entire error message to the post and see if that helps

Comment: @brothir It's _not_ too much code. This is the minimal amount that actually shows the real problem.

Comment: @CraigEstey, the code you see in the question has been edited many times. The initial code posted was hundreds of lines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're faulting in the *first* `MPI_Wait` (for rank 0). This is step 7 in the example code below.

Using `mpirun -np 2 ./whatever`:

It appears that `sReqD` is *not* being set correctly. This is set at step 5 by rank 1.

But, step 7 is being executed by rank 0, which does *not* set `sReqD`.

So, you need to adjust your `if` statements to match up correctly for which rank does which `MPI_Wait`, etc.

---

Here is your code with some debug `printf` statements:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <mpi.h>

int
main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    /* MPI Specific Variables */
    int my_size,
     my_rank,
     up,
     down;
    MPI_Request reqU,
     reqD,
     sreqU,
     sreqD;
    MPI_Status rUstatus,
     rDstatus,
     sUstatus,
     sDstatus;

    /* Physical Dimensions */
    double Linner = 5.0;                /* mm */
    double Rinner = 1.0;                /* mm */
    double phi_0 = 1000.0;

    /*V*/
        /* Other Variables */
    int grid_size = 100;
    int slice;
    int x,
     y;
    double grid_res_y = 0.2;
    double grid_res_x = 0.1;

    int xboundary,
     yboundary;

    MPI_Init(&argc, &argv);
    MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &my_rank);
    MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &my_size);

    /* Determining neighbours */
    /* if statemets used to stop highest and lowest rank neighbours arent
    outside 0 - my_size-1 range of ranks */
    if (my_rank != 0) {
        up = my_rank - 1;
    }
    else {
        up = 0;
    }

    if (my_rank != my_size - 1) {
        down = my_rank + 1;
    }
    else {
        down = my_size - 1;
    }

    printf("my_rank=%d my_size=%d up=%d down=%d\n",my_rank,my_size,up,down);

    /* cross-check: presumed my_size is a factor of gridsize else there are
    odd sized slices and this is not coded for */
    if (grid_size % my_size != 0) {
        printf("ERROR - number of procs =  %d, this is not a factor of grid_size %d\n", my_size, grid_size);
        exit(0);
    }

    /* Set Up Distributed Data Approach */
    slice = grid_size / my_size;

    /* y grid index of inner conductor wall */
    yboundary = Linner / grid_res_y;
    /* x grid and individual array index of inner conductor wall */
    xboundary = Rinner / grid_res_x;

    if (my_rank == 0) {
        printf("Linner=%g grid_res_y=%g yboundary=%d\n",
            Linner,grid_res_y,yboundary);
        printf("Rinner=%g grid_res_x=%g xboundary=%d\n",
            Rinner,grid_res_x,xboundary);
        printf("slice=%d grid_size=%d phi=%ld\n",
            slice,grid_size,sizeof(double) * (slice + 2) * grid_size);
    }

    /* extra 2 rows to allow for halo data */
    double phi[slice + 2][grid_size];

    for (y = 0; y < slice + 2; y++) {
        for (x = 0; x < grid_size; x++) {
            phi[y][x] = 0.0;
        }
    }

    /* Boundary Containing rank does 2 loops. One over part with inner
    conductor and one over part without inner conductor */
    if (my_rank == 0) {
        for (y = 0; y < slice + 1; y++) {
            for (x = xboundary; x < grid_size; x++) {
                phi[y][x] = phi_0;
            }
        }
    }

    if (my_rank < my_size - 1) {
        /* send top most strip up one node to be recieved as bottom halo */
        printf("1: my_rank=%d MPI_Isend\n",my_rank);
        MPI_Isend(&phi[1][0], grid_size, MPI_DOUBLE, down, 1, MPI_COMM_WORLD,
            &sreqU);

        /* recv top halo from up one node */
        printf("2: my_rank=%d MPI_Irecv\n",my_rank);
        MPI_Irecv(&phi[slice + 1][0], grid_size, MPI_DOUBLE, down, 2,
            MPI_COMM_WORLD, &reqU);

        printf("3: my_rank=%d\n",my_rank);
    }

    if (my_rank > 0) {
        /* recv top halo from down one node */
        printf("4: my_rank=%d MPI_Irecv\n",my_rank);
        MPI_Irecv(&phi[0][0], grid_size, MPI_DOUBLE, up, 2, MPI_COMM_WORLD,
            &reqD);

        /* send bottom most strip down one node to be recieved as top halo */
        printf("5: my_rank=%d MPI_Isend\n",my_rank);
        MPI_Isend(&phi[slice][0], grid_size, MPI_DOUBLE, up, 1, MPI_COMM_WORLD,
            &sreqD);

        printf("6: my_rank=%d\n",my_rank);
    }

    if (my_rank < my_size - 1) {
        /* Wait for send to down one rank to complete */
        printf("7: my_rank=%d\n",my_rank);
        MPI_Wait(&sreqD, &sDstatus);
        printf("8: my_rank=%d\n",my_rank);

        /* Wait for recieve from up one rank to complete */
        printf("9: my_rank=%d\n",my_rank);
        MPI_Wait(&reqD, &rDstatus);
        printf("10: my_rank=%d\n",my_rank);
    }

    if (my_rank > 0) {
        /* Wait for send to up down one rank to complete */
        printf("11: my_rank=%d\n",my_rank);
        MPI_Wait(&sreqU, &sUstatus);
        printf("12: my_rank=%d\n",my_rank);

        /* Wait for recieve from down one rank to complete */
        printf("12: my_rank=%d\n",my_rank);
        MPI_Wait(&reqU, &rUstatus);
        printf("13: my_rank=%d\n",my_rank);
    }

    MPI_Finalize();

    return 0;
}
```

---

Here is the output. Notice that step 7 prints (which is *before* the first `MPI_Wait` for rank 0). But, rank 0 never gets to step 8 (the `printf` *after* that call)

```
my_rank=0 my_size=2 up=0 down=1
Linner=5 grid_res_y=0.2 yboundary=25
Rinner=1 grid_res_x=0.1 xboundary=10
slice=50 grid_size=100 phi=41600
1: my_rank=0 MPI_Isend
2: my_rank=0 MPI_Irecv
3: my_rank=0
7: my_rank=0
my_rank=1 my_size=2 up=0 down=1
4: my_rank=1 MPI_Irecv
5: my_rank=1 MPI_Isend
6: my_rank=1
11: my_rank=1
[manderly:230404] *** Process received signal ***
[manderly:230403] *** Process received signal ***
[manderly:230403] Signal: Segmentation fault (11)
[manderly:230403] Signal code: Address not mapped (1)
[manderly:230403] Failing at address: 0x58
[manderly:230404] Signal: Segmentation fault (11)
[manderly:230404] Signal code: Address not mapped (1)
[manderly:230404] Failing at address: 0x58
[manderly:230403] [ 0] [manderly:230404] [ 0] /lib64/libpthread.so.0(+0x121c0)/lib64/libpthread.so.0(+0x121c0)[0x7fa5478341c0]
[0x7fa0ebe951c0]
[manderly:230404] [ 1] [manderly:230403] [ 1] /usr/lib64/openmpi/lib/libmpi.so.20(ompi_request_default_wait+0x31)[0x7fa0ec0e9a81]
[manderly:230404] [ 2] /usr/lib64/openmpi/lib/libmpi.so.20(ompi_request_default_wait+0x31)[0x7fa547a88a81]
[manderly:230403] [ 2] /usr/lib64/openmpi/lib/libmpi.so.20(PMPI_Wait+0x60)[0x7fa0ec12c350]
[manderly:230404] [ 3] ./fix2[0x400f93]
[manderly:230404] [ 4] /usr/lib64/openmpi/lib/libmpi.so.20(PMPI_Wait+0x60)[0x7fa547acb350]
[manderly:230403] [ 3] ./fix2[0x400ef7]
/lib64/libc.so.6(__libc_start_main+0xea)[0x7fa0ebaedfea]
[manderly:230404] [ 5] ./fix2[0x40081a[manderly:230403] [ 4] ]
[manderly:230404] *** End of error message ***
/lib64/libc.so.6(__libc_start_main+0xea)[0x7fa54748cfea]
[manderly:230403] [ 5] ./fix2[0x40081a]
[manderly:230403] *** End of error message ***
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
mpirun noticed that process rank 0 with PID 0 on node manderly exited on signal 11 (Segmentation fault).
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: As a matter of style, you can declare an array of 4 requests **all** set to `MPI_REQUEST_NULL` at the beginning of each iteration, and then `MPI_Wait all(4, ...)`. Or you can set `up` and `down` to `MPI_PROC_NULL` on the first and last ranks and always `MPI_Isend()` and `MPI_Irecv()`.